# React-native debugger runs faster than no debugging

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react-native 0.63 and doing a simple 1sec interval when I mount a component.

e.g.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // Start elapsed ticker
    const levelTicker = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('TICK...')
      setSeconds((s) => s + 1)
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      console.log('CLEARING INTERVAL')
      clearInterval(levelTicker)
    }
  }, [])
```

When I run the app without debugger on, the app will render the timer correctly (1 second every render). But when I activate the debugger, it runs much more quickly--0.00001s every render--which makes it almost impossible to click buttons or do whatever on the app. The same thing happens when trying to `onPress` on Buttons that has `onLongPress`. It will run so fast, that even a quick tap will trigger the `onLongPress`.

Any clues how to make at least to run at normal speed? Thanks in advance.

Device:
OnePlus 7T, Android 10

Answer (score 0):

There's a [react-native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4470) for `setInterval` firing far too soon in Chrome Debugger. It's from 2015-2018, but looks like the bug has returned.

I've just encountered it (March 2024) while debugging a RN0.66.5 app on a new computer (Chrome v122 on an Mac Air M3).